# SWR returning incorrect data after second request

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

After my second request o get data to `/api/individual` endpoint, when I query that endpoint without refreshing my browser useSWR returns an incorrect payload. However, when I reload the webpage it returns the correct data. Here is the data the first time I receive it. endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/api/individual?section=Congress%20Services&individual_id=1`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "61ece7a3570c0b5a211c86b0"
            },
            "individual_id": 1,
            "sections": {
                "Event Services": {
                    "Choose language for translation": "Russian",
                    "Do you need a letter of invitation": "No",
                    "Family Program (Extra fee)": "No",
                    "Translation needed": "Yes"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After I load the same endpoint but request different data `http://localhost:3000/api/individual?section=Agreement%20to%20publish&individual_id=1`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "61ece7a3570c0b5a211c86b0"
            },
            "individual_id": 1,
            "sections": {
                "Agreement to publish": {
                    "Agreement to publish": "No"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I then load the previous endpoint.. but receive different data than the first time. endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/api/individual?section=Congress%20Services&individual_id=1`

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61ece7a3570c0b5a211c86b0"
        },
        "individual_id": 1,
        "sections": {
            "Event Services": {
                "Do you need a letter of invitation to obtain a visa": "No",
                "Family Program (Extra fee)": "No",
                "Translation needed": "Yes"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

However if I look at the network tab I notice that the network tab returned the correct data but useSWR did not. I also notice that if I add a random compare option to useSWR such as...

```
options: {
  compare: (a, b) => {
    console.log("A", a)
    console.log("B", b)

  }
}
```

The bug goes away... any idea what could be causing this?

My fetcher and useSWR functions look like...

```
async function fetcher(...args) {
  const url = args[0]
  const token = args[1]
  const method = args.length > 2 ? args[2] : 'GET'
  const body = args.length > 3 ? { body: JSON.stringify(args[3]) } : {}
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: method,

    headers:
      method != 'GET'
        ? {
            Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        : {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
    ...body,
  })

  if (!res.ok) {
    const error = new Error('An error occurred while fetching the data.')
    // Attach extra info to the error object.
    error.info = await res.json()
    error.status = res.status
    throw error
  }

  return res.json()
}

function useSWRFetch({ endpoint, token, options = null, condition=true }) {
  const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR(token && condition ? [endpoint, token] : null, fetcher, options)

  return {
    mutate: mutate,
    data: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    error: error,
  }
}
```

And this is how I call it...

```
const formQuestionsResponse = useSWRFetch({
    endpoint: `/api/individual?section=${section}&individual_id=${id}`,
    token: authToken,
    condition: isCurrentSelectedTab,
    // options: {
    //   compare: (a, b) => {
    //     console.log("A", a, 'B', b)
    //   }
    // }
  })
```

I also noticed that if I console.log my data in my fetcher function it returns the correct data that I see in my network tab, but if I console.log it after it has has gone through useSWR the data is missing one property.

Comment: What is the request like, what are the SWR configs that you are using?

Comment: It might be a library bug, or some of internal cache mechanism you aren't aware of. I recommend you file a  github issue in official github repo. The maintainer is actively responding all sorts of questions. It may benefit other devs. https://github.com/vercel/swr

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this I performed a cleanup in my useEffect. I set the data back to `null` on the cleanup when clicking between sections. I believe that there was sort of memory leak happening.

Answer (score 0):

This data is not reset when you encounter an error because maybe you want to show the optimistic data.
You can clear the data by calling `mutate(null)` but be careful it will reset the data (in the swr-cache as well?).

In the case of *useSWRMutation* you can make use of the *reset* function which will clear out all (data, error, isMutating)

Reference: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#return-values-1